# Elasticsearch: Async "delete by query" and index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-usage.html) plugins for elastic search.

I have a index products with a integer field size. I want delete all document with size 10. I have over 5000 documents with size 10.

If i try:

```
DELETE /products/product/_query?q=size:10
```

this query requires over 2 minutes (delete by query is really slow), if i post a new `product` with size 10 during deleting, eg.:

```
POST /products/product/
{
    "size": 10
}
```

what happens?

my new `product` is saved or deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete by query will only delete the version of the document that was visible to search at the time the request was executed. Any documents that have been reindexed or updated during execution will not be deleted

[click here for more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-usage.html)